# EXCEL - Search between two rows, find identival data and add data from a third row

Tags: excel

I have two pages in excel.
In the 1st page I have:

| name | result1 |
| --- | --- |
| aaaaa | row1 |
| bbbbb | row2 |
| ccccc | row3 |
| ddddd | row4 |

the 2nd page is (**note: "name" column isn't in order as in the 1st page!**):

| name | result2 |
| --- | --- |
| ccccc | data3 |
| aaaaa | data1 |
| ddddd | data4 |
| bbbbb | data2 |

And I want to match between the data from the 1st and 2nd page of the "name" column and add to the 1st page a 3rd column with data of the "result2" column.

Comment: A normal [VLOOKUP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/vlookup-942f678a-1bfc-4ccf-8dfa-f5057ded5c65)/[XLOOKUP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929) would do this just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the exact reason why `VLookup` has been invented, here you have an example:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2;Sheet1!$A$1:$B$5;2;FALSE)
```

As you mention, there are two sheets, "Sheet1" and "Sheet2", and I'm currently present in "Sheet2".

I'm looking for the value of "A2" ("Sheet2", cell "A2") inside the array "Sheet1!$A1:$B5". Let's explain that array:

- It is present in the other sheet, "Sheet1", hence the "Sheet1!" prefix.
- I am looking in the array "A1:B5". I need column "B" too in order to get the result too (the requested value is present in column "B"). I'm using absolute references "$A$1" instead of "A1", because later, after I have typed my formula, I will drag it to the next cell. When doing that, I'll need to look for "A2" (not "A1" anymore) in the array "Sheet1!A1:B5" (here "A1" may not be modified into "A2", hence the absolute references).
- Last but not least, I'm looking for an exact match (`FALSE`), not an approximate one (`TRUE)`.

Have fun! :-)